# Reference Javascript Array (JSON Format) with unknown array key

Tags: javascript, json

How would you reference a value in a Javascript object without the key?

So, given the object:

```
var JSONdata= [ 
    {"index":"1","var1":1,"var2":2}, 
    {"index":"2","var1":3,"var2":2}, 
    {"index":"3","var1":3,"var2":1}, 
    {"index":"4","var1":2,"var2":1}, 
    {"index":"5","var1":1,"var2":3}, 
];
```

Say I want to reference the values of var1 and var2 in a loop, but the names "var1" and "var2" change and the number of variables also changes.

So in Pseudocode:

```
while ( i < JSONdata.length ) {
   for (j = 1 to Num_variables) {
       Give me the value for varN
   next j
   }
i++
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to exclude the `index` property but include all other properties of each object?

Comment: You're right in your assumption Russ.  I am using the data to construct a plot and the `index` variable is my x-axis, then I want to loop through every other variable.  The answers below are right on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var JSONdata= [ 
  {"index":"1","var1":1,"var2":2}, 
  {"index":"2","var1":3,"var2":2}, 
  {"index":"3","var1":3,"var2":1}, 
  {"index":"4","var1":2,"var2":1}, 
  {"index":"5","var1":1,"var2":3}
]; 

var fields=[
  "var1",
  "var2"
];

for(var i=0, ii=JSONdata.length; i<ii; i++){
  for(var j=0, jj=fields.length; j<jj; j++){
    $('#hello').html($('#hello').html()+' '+JSONdata[i][fields[j]]);
  }
  $('#hello').html($('#hello').html()+' '+'<br/>');
}
```

see there http://jsbin.com/ufege4/edit

Comment: Perfect answer Avrelian.  This allows for any variables names rather than just `var1` `var2` etc.  Thanks and I really like that jsbin.com preview tool.

Answer (score 1):

The `obj.propertyName` notation in JavaScript is syntactic sugar for `obj['propertyName']` -- So, you can access your vars using: `JSONData[i]['var'+j];`

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I had tried `JSONdata[i][j]` with no success but did not realize I could use a numerical value for the first array object dimension and a string value for the second dimension.